# How to get specific content from JSON response using context.expand?

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

I'm trying to use context.expand to get response and specific content from within the response,

```
def response = context.expand( '${Ranks of documents with SSE hits reflects scores#Response}' )
```

I also need to get specific detail from within the response, say if response has an array of ranks:

```
"ranks":[2234, 1234]
```

How can get both values of ranks?

Comment: maybe if you provide and example of the JSON input

Comment: is this helpful http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/using-$select,-$expand,-and-$value

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`JsonSlurper`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) from the groovy script testStep, supposing you get the follow JSON:

```
{"ranks":[2234, 1234]}
```

from your code:

```
def response = context.expand( '${Ranks of documents with SSE hits reflects scores#Response}')
```

You can use the `JsonSlurper` as follows to get your "ranks" values:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
// here I use this JSON as example, but you can 
// parse directly your response which you get with context.expand
def response = '{"ranks":[2234, 1234]}' 
def jsonRoot = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)
log.info jsonRoot.ranks[0]
log.info jsonRoot.ranks[1]
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

Internally, SoapUI will convert *almost* anything to XML. You could grab just that node with `${step_name#ResponseAsXml}`, and then parse it however you need to. Something like:

```
def ranksString = context.expand( '${Ranks of documents with SSE hits reflects scores#ResponseAsXml#//*:ranks}' )
def ranksArray = ranksString.split(",").trim()
log.info ranksArray[0]
log.info ranksArray[1]
```